# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: Nodeshierachy.getAccountHierarchiesQuick()

Tags: apex, class

I'm calling a method `Nodeshierachy.getAccountHierarchiesQuick()` :

```
public class Nodeshierachy {
// Get complete account hierarchies to 4 levels ed
public static Map<Id,HierarchyNode> getAccountHierarchiesQuick(Set<Id> top_acct_ids) {
    Map<Id,HierarchyNode> nodes = new Map<Id,HierarchyNode>();
    Set<Id> parent_acc_ids = top_acct_ids;

    while (parent_acc_ids.size() > 0) {
        Map<Id,Account> subordinate_accounts =
        new Map<Id,Account>([
            SELECT Id, Name,
                   ParentID,
                   Parent.ParentID,
                   Parent.Parent.ParentID,
                   Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentID
            FROM   Account
            WHERE (ParentId IN :parent_acc_ids) OR
                  (Parent.ParentId IN :parent_acc_ids) OR
                  (Parent.Parent.ParentId IN :parent_acc_ids) OR
                  (Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId IN :parent_acc_ids)]);

        List<Account> level1_accs = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> level2_accs = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> level3_accs = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> level4_accs = new List<Account>();`
```

Comment: It seems like, based on this question and previous questions, you're working on projects far too complicated for your current skill set. I strongly advise working on something simpler to begin with, or starting with Trailhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that :

```
List<SObject> results = [SELECT ID FROM Account];
Set<Id> resultIds = (new Map<Id, SObject>(results)).keySet();

Map<Id,HierarchyNode> yourMap = Nodeshierachy.getAccountHierarchiesQuick(resultIds);

// And then do what you want with yourMap
```

Comment: this results in: Illegal assignment from Map<Id,getHierarchies.Nodeshierachy> to Map<Id,HierarchyNode>

Comment: `getAccountHierarchiesQuick()` method return `Map<Id,HierarchyNode>` object like `yourMap` object, so I don't see why you have this error... Your copy my code, right ?

Comment: Nodeshierachy.getAccountHierarchiesQuick(resultIds);   returns  Map<Id,getHierarchies.HierarchyNode>
 an not Map<Id,HierarchyNode>

Comment: Map<Id,Nodeshierachy.HierarchyNode>  did work thanks anyway!